# Commas in script database

Tags: jquery, regex, file

I've got this script:

```
$.get('file.txt', function(x) {

var i;
var pos = 0;
var availableTags = [];

x = x.split(/[\;,\n]+/);

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i = i + 2)
  availableTags[pos++] = x[i];

console.log(availableTags);

$(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});

}, 'text');
```

I want it to read the first column of this file.txt

```
Supermarket;big shop where a wide range of products is sold
Station;a place where you can take a train, a bus, etc.
School;place where students learn
```

Though commas are not spliters, the script understands they are, and after the commas "," of the second line the reading is mistaken, as it understand bus, etc as items. Any suggestion?

Comment: why dont you remove comma from the reg-exp , `x = x.split(/[\;\n]+/);`

Comment: is file.txt given and no subject to change? the server sided response should try to produce some object format like: { tag: "supermarket", desc: "big shop..."}, { tag: "station", desc: "a place..."} and so on. this would make the client handling way easier

Comment: Well, I'm sorry but it was as simple as dreamweiver answer. Thought I had tried... that's the problem of working till late. Should i remove the question?

Comment: @dreamweiver: Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: sure thing  bro @stribizhev :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the comma from the reg-exp `x = x.split(/[\;\n]+/);` because your regular-expression is splitting the string based on both `;` &`,`.

Below is the corrected code

**JS CODE:**

```
$.get('file.txt', function(x) {
  var i;
  var pos = 0;
  var availableTags = [];
  x = x.split(/[\;\n]+/);  //removed ',' from regular-expression 
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i = i + 2){
     availableTags[pos++] = x[i];
  }

  console.log(availableTags);

 $(function() {
     $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
     });
 });
}, 'text');
```

Comment: Just FYI: in JS, there is no point escaping `;`, neither inside a character class nor outside of it. Just `/[;\n]+/` is enough.

Comment: oh that's interesting , never knew that